# install perl.i386 on 64-bit CentOS

Tags: centos, lamp

I installing Sun Web Stack 1.6 Linux on CentOS 5.5.
However it complain on missing 32-bit perl

```
[root@myserver sunwebstack]# ./install amp
sun-apache22-perl-2.0.4-b10.i386.rpm...
WS011 Installation of package sun-apache22-perl-2.0.4-b10.i386.rpm failed with 
Preparing packages for installation...
error: Failed dependencies :
perl >= 5.8.8 is needed by sun-apache22-perl-2.0.4-b10
error: %pre(sun-apache22-perl-2.0.4-b10.i386) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
error:   install: %pre scriptlet failed (2), skipping sun-apache22-perl-2.0.4-b10
```

I tried to install the 32-bit perl but it complains on conflict with the existing 64-bit perl

```
Transaction Check Error:
  package perl-5.8.8-32.el5_5.2.x86_64 (which is newer than perl-5.8.8-32.el5_5.1.i386) is already installed
  file /usr/share/man/man1/c2ph.1.gz from install of perl-5.8.8-32.el5_5.1.i386 conflicts with file from package perl-5.8.8-32.el5_5.2.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/cpan.1.gz from install of perl-5.8.8-32.el5_5.1.i386 conflicts with file from package perl-5.8.8-32.el5_5.2.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/dprofpp.1.gz from install of perl-5.8.8-32.el5_5.1.i386 conflicts with file from package perl-5.8.8-32.el5_5.2.x86_64
```

How can I (force?) install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with force install the 32-bit download from CentOS mirror with following command.

```
rpm -hUv --force http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/i386/CentOS/perl-5.8.8-27.el5.i386.rpm
```

Comment: You installed an older version, which means that you clobbered several files from the newer package with files from the older package. Needing to force it is a vary good sign that you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Maybe I did it the wrong way. I did yum install per.i386 but it fail. it return error on conflict with the 64-bit. so I have to force install it. i have no problem reboot the system several times and its has been running well for the last 5 hours. *finger cross*

Answer (score 0):

Don't. Get the `perl.i386` package that exactly matches the `perl.x86_64` package that is already installed, and install that.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean, where I should get the perl.i386 package then?

Comment: From the same place you got the perl.x86_64 package. But make sure that the versions and releases both match.

Comment: the perl.x86_64 come with the CentOS 5.5 itself. i think its been update b4. tried search the 32-bit on the CD installer but no luck.

Comment: Then try `yum install perl.i386` in order to get it from where you got the perl.x86_64 package.